# WPF Commands - how to consume in user control

Tags: .net, wpf, user-controls

I want to put some functionality of my WPF app into user controls, mainly to reduce the clutter in my main window.

At the moment I have the following commands defined in my main window. These are consumed by `ToolBar` items and also menu items...

```
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="Close" Executed="CloseCommandHandler" />
    <CommandBinding Command="local:AppCommands.OpenAttributes" Executed="OpenAttributesHandler" CanExecute="OpenAttributesCanExecute" />
</Window.CommandBindings>
```

Is there a way I can consume these same commands from a user control nested inside my main window?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, through binding:

```
<Button Command="{Binding MyCommand}" />
```

If it's a user control, just make it expose a dependency property of type `ICommand`. Also, MyCommand must be inside the ViewModel.

**EDIT:**
Say you have a `Button` nested within your UserControl:

```
<UserControl x:Name="MyUc">
...
   <Button Command={Binding NestedCommand, ElementName=MyUc} />
...
</UserControl>
```

In the code behind of the user control, you need to expose "NestedCommand" as a dependency property:

```
#region NestedCommand
    public ICommand NestedCommand
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(NestedCommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(NestedCommandProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for NestedCommand.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty NestedCommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("NestedCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(MyUserControlClassName), new UIPropertyMetadata(MyDefaultValue));
    #endregion
```

Set "MyDefaultValue" to null, and "MyUserControlClassName" to the name of your UserControl, let's call it Bob for a minute.

Now when you will use that UserControl, it will expose a NestedCommand property:

```
<Window>
...
<my:Bob NestedCommand="{Binding MyCommand}" />
...
</Window>
```

"my" is the xmlns namespace where your UserControls are defined, of course.
And MyCommand must be defined in your ViewModel a.k.a the object you put as DataContext of your view.
You can find out about it all over the web, but it boils down to creating a class that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, adding an `ICommand` to it, and then in the Window's constructor:

```
public MyWindow()
{
...
   this.DataContext = new MyViewModel();
...
}
```

Comment: Im not using MVVM at present. Could you provide a few notes (+links?) on how to implement this?

Comment: Alright, i'll edit my answer. But you do need to set a DataContext for your view to use Bindings.

Comment: Just trying to implement this. Where you define the user control in the main window, you set the user controls command property = "{Binding MyCommand}" - is "MyCommand" the name of a command defined in the Window.CommandBindings collection? If you wouldnt mind clarifying where MyCommand is defined that would be appreciated.

Comment: MyCommand is the name of a public property of type ICommand that should be in the object set as DataContext of your XAML.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. You have to make a command binding in your user control to that command.

Comment: So similar code to what I have posted but inside the user command?